# libgdx some keypresses faster than others?

Tags: java, input, libgdx

I started coding with libgdx recently and built a little "move around in a world" game. The problem is that it is faster going Up and Left (W and A) than going Right and Down. There is no difference in the code of W,A and of D,S.
Here's my code for the input handling that just gets called every frame after "render":

```
public void processInput() {
    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    System.out.println(1.0/delta);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.A)) {
        player.posX -= 100 * delta;
        player.startAnimation(0); // Animation 0 = LEFT
        elapsedTime = 0;
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.D)) {
        player.posX += 100 * delta;
        player.startAnimation(1); // Animation 1 = RIGHT
        elapsedTime = 0;
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.W)) {
        player.posY -= 100 * delta;
        player.startAnimation(2); // Animation 2 = BACK
        elapsedTime = 0;
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.S)) {
        player.posY += 100 * delta;
        player.startAnimation(3); // Animation 3 = FRONT
        elapsedTime = 0;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)){
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }

    boolean pressed = false;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
        player.posX -= 100 * delta;
        pressed = true;
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) {
        player.posX += 100 * delta;
        pressed = true;
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
        player.posY -= 100 * delta;
        pressed = true;
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
        player.posY += 100 * delta;
        pressed = true;
    }
    if (!pressed) {
        player.stopAnimation();
    }

    if(player.posX < 0){
        player.posX = 0;
    }
    if(player.posY < 0){
        player.posY = 0;
    }
    if(player.posX > world.sizeX()*50){
        player.posX = world.sizeX()*50;
    }
    if(player.posY > world.sizeY()*50){
        player.posY = world.sizeY()*50;;
    }

    player.update(delta);
}
```

Also here a dropbox link with the full code: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p8umkyiyd663now/AAC4zt716rII-8sQpEbfuNuZa?dl=0

Comment: Try running the game in a perfect square window and see if you are experiencing the same behaviour? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079122/how-to-change-libgdx-different-window-size/21083929

Comment: Yes sir. Same thing with a square window.

Comment: And your camera's view port is that also a perfect square?

Comment: yeah I just take the Gdx.graphics.getWidth/getHeight as camera viewport.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is your screen resolution? I remember having the issue a while ago with XNA. Sorry I cant be of anymore help.

Comment: I think u are thinking of this problem as of a stretching of the screen by the screen resolution which would be resolved with a perfect square but I can see the X and Y values of the player position changing faster and not just a faster movement.

Comment: I don't see what's causing the mismatched speeds, but did notice that you're moving your player twice on the first frame that you press any key. I think you want to remove all the position changes in the just-pressed section at the top. And a suggestion: your code could be simplified by using an InputProcessor.

Comment: I guess the problem is not in this part of code, I have copied it and tested and it works as expected. Of course I didn't checked player's `update` method.

Comment: ok weird. I'll provide a quick dropbox link of the whole code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you for the suggestion with the InputProcessor. I will look into it. Also, I already saw the double movement after I posted the code here and will change it after this problem is resolved.

Comment: I still don't see what's causing the issue, but noticed a couple other bugs. You should reset `elapsedTime` to 0 in `Player.startAnimation(...)` and then remove `elapsedTime = 0` lines in this `processInput()` method, since it's not the elpased time that has to do with the player's animation.  And do not instantiate a new BitmapFont object in the render loop because it is a heavy object that uses native memory, and it must be disposed before its reference is lost if you don't want a memory leak.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't know if you messed something up or if the dropbox isn't synchronized but the elapsedTime in startAnimation is already how you described it. Also the BitmapFont is just a temporary thing I did to check if the X and Y are really changing faster or not.

Comment: I see the elapsed time is correct in the Player.startAnimation() method, but why are you also resetting GameState.elapsedTime when the animation changes? Anyway, that's unrelated to this issue. It has me completely stumped. Does the effect get reversed if you swap the order of your four `if/elseif` statements? i.e. swap W and S and swap A and D.

Comment: Negative sir. I also removed the double movement with "isKeyJustPressed" and the elapsedTime=0 in it now. The problem is still the same.

Comment: I found the issue, I will post an answer in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you store player position as integer values. Player velocity is so small after delta calculation that converting float value to integer has a massive impact on speed.

**Comparison**

Delta position as integer is 2 in case of W and A keys and 1 on S and D.

Delta position as float is around 1.7 in both cases.

**Solution**: use float values to store player position. Using integer values makes sense only in case of some grid based game.

```
public float posX;
public float posY;
```

Comment: OMG thank you man. I now remember that I didn't want to forget to change the position from int to float to prevent precision issues of calculations. It resolved the issue.